# Need to count WebbApps, SC and Sites in the farm using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, counting, sitecollection

Hi I´m tryin to get a count for all my Web App in the SahrePoint Farm, once that done I want to count the Site Colletions within the Webapps and the Sites with in the SC.I´m totally new in programing and this is my frist PwerShell script.

This is the code I´m trying to use.

```
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null)             
{            
 Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell            
}

$Get-SPWebApplication 

ForEach-Object{

      ForEach($SPWebApplication in $Get-SPWebApplication)
        {
        Get-SPSite -Limit All | 
        Select -ExpandProperty AllWebs | 
        ft url, Title, Created -auto | 
        out-string -width 1024 > c:\Sc.txt
}
}
```

Can someone advice? Again this sis the first time I try do thing programing!

Tks.

Answer (score 3):

Try running the following PowerShell script in a SharePoint Management Shell and see if it meets your needs:

```
Write-Host "Web Applications in Farm"
$WebApplications = Get-SPWebApplication
$WebApplications | Measure-Object | Format-List Count

ForEach($WebApplication in $WebApplications){
    Write-Host "Site Collections in the Web Application named " $WebApplication.Name
    $WebApplication.Sites | Measure-Object | Format-List Count

    ForEach($SiteCollection in $WebApplication.Sites){
        Write-Host "Webs (Sub-Sites) in the Site Collection with the URL " $SiteCollection.Url
        Write-Host "`nCount : " $SiteCollection.AllWebs.Count "`n`n`n"

    }

}
```